# Relative path imports inside templates loaded with a Jinja PrefixLoader

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am working on a Flask app which uses jinja2's PrefixLoader and PackageLoader in conjunction as follows:

```
app.jinja_loader = PrefixLoader({
    'app': PackageLoader('flask_skeleton_ui'),
    'govuk_frontend': PackageLoader('govuk_frontend_jinja', 'govuk-frontend/src/')
})
```

Thereby allowing me to load templates like this:

```
{% extends "govuk_frontend/template.html" %}
```

However, jinja appears to be struggling to find templates *inside* the govuk_frontend package which use relative imports, such as:

```
{% from "./components/skip-link/macro.html" import govukSkipLink %}
```

What I would expect to happen is for that to be resolved relative to the parent template inside the package. But it doesn't seem to be and a TemplateNotFound exception is thrown.

Should this work? Or have I misunderstood something?